# Open a link from within fancybox without triggering the 'afterClose' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So, I have a page with links that open other files in a fancybox.

The problem is that, when I click on a link inside fancybox, I want it to load in a fancybox as well, but if I add the fancybox class to these links it closes the existing fancybox and tries to open another one, but that doesn't happen because i have a `afterClose` function that reloads the page.

Is there any way to either load a new page in the same fancybox or override the `afterClose` function when opening new links ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : It also has to work for fancyboxes that are divs withing the same file...
For example in index.php there is a link `a href="#popup"` and in the `div#popup` there are links that need to open in the same facynox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Add the onclick event for the link which is inside the fancy box

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: location.href='your page link here';">Click</a>
```

Try this now.

Comment: then it opens is in the whole document, not in the facnybox

Comment: I added the parent by mistake.. I have updated my answer. Please try it.

Comment: That works for external files, but not for divs... please read the edit on the OP

Comment: I think that is not possible to open up inline div and another page. For other page to open up n fancy box you need type : iframe

Comment: `I think that is not possible to open up inline div and another page` @DinoPrašo : if that's not possible, how come this is the correct answer?

Comment: @JFK may be Dino Praso has changed the way he wanted to work. :)

Comment: @Majeed : well, Yunus' statement `that is not possible` is actually possible but if everybody is happy with this patched solution, so be it.

Comment: @JFK that's exactly what I mean. If every one is OK with the solution then its well and good.